# How do I remove full name from owner column within file manager?

Tags: nautilus, customization, filemanager

Within the file manager (Nautilus), you can customize it a bit through Edit -> Preferences.

I set default view to `List View` and added some additional default columns. Adding the `owner` column displays the machine username and full name of the user (given on install). Like this:

```
Name       | Size    | Group   | Owner            | Permissions
file.txt   | 1.0 kB  | john    | john - John Doe  | -rw-r--r--
```

How do I remove the full name? So it displays like this:

```
Name       | Size    | Group   | Owner  | Permissions
file.txt   | 1.0 kB  | john    | john   | -rw-r--r--
```

See how it says `john - John Doe`?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: I think that you need re-build the OS, because it is hardcore code. But maybe I'm wrong and someone know an easy way..

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand the point here, but I think that is not so easy as you may think (I wish to be wrong). Let see what the others users think..

Comment: KDE's Dolphin displays just the username. Not sure whether you can get Nautilus to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

As has been alluded to, this is behavior that is coded into the Nautilus application.

However, you can get around the functionality by changing your "Real Name" to be the same as your username ... **Nautilus only displays a second "name" in the owner column if the real name is different from the username.**

You should be able to change your "real name" in System-Administration-Users and Groups.

I had trouble getting the changes to stick for me, so I manually changed it by editing `/etc/passwd`.

You will have to restart all nautilus instances for the change to take effect.